# On podman container restore i get a segmentation fault, some one knows how to solve this?

Tags: containers, restore, checkpoint

Executed command

- podman container restore

Current environment

`Linux pop-os 6.0.12-76060006-generic #202212290932~1674139725~22.04~ca93ccf SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu J x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

runc version

```
runc version 1.1.0-0ubuntu1.1
spec: 1.0.2-dev
go: go1.18.1
libseccomp: 2.5.3
```

containerd version
`1.5.9-0ubuntu3.1`

criu version

`3.16`

Container error debug log

```
(00.035080) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562a90583000 -> 0x562a905bf000, 0x7 0x4032 -1)
(00.035084) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562a905bf000 -> 0x562a9853f000, 0x0 0x4032 -1)
(00.035088) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562b0ee96000 -> 0x562b0f6b9000, 0x1 0x12 19)
(00.035093) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562b0f6b9000 -> 0x562b0f6bb000, 0x5 0x12 19)
(00.035098) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562b0f6bc000 -> 0x562b10f15000, 0x5 0x12 19)
(00.035102) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562b11096000 -> 0x562b11097000, 0x5 0x12 19)
(00.035107) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562b11097000 -> 0x562b13d8d000, 0x3 0x12 19)
(00.035112) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562b13d8d000 -> 0x562b13e83000, 0x3 0x12 19)
(00.035116) pie: 1:     mmap(0x562b13e83000 -> 0x562b13e9a000, 0x3 0x12 19)
(00.035153) Error (criu/cr-restore.c:1492): 61906 stopped by signal 11: Segmentation fault
(00.035370) mnt: Switching to new ns to clean ghosts
(00.035618) Error (criu/cr-restore.c:2447): Restoring FAILED.
```

Container restore succeded

Comment: Which command did you run? If you got a segmentation fault when running a Podman command, I'm sure the Podman developers would like to know. Maybe you could post a message in https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions  ?

Comment: edited To add command context

Answer (score 0):

Never more, I solved it updating criu version to 3.17, (pop os comes with 3.16).